# Refactoring Ruby : Converting string array to int array

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm refactoring a checkers program, and I am trying to process a players move request (in the form of "3, 3, 5, 5" for example) into an int array. I have the following method, but it doesn't feel as Ruby-like as I know it could be:

```
def translate_move_request_to_coordinates(move_request)
    return_array = []
    coords_array = move_request.chomp.split(',')
    coords_array.each_with_index do |i, x|
      return_array[x] = i.to_i
    end
    return_array
  end
```

I have the following RSpec test with it.

```
it "translates a move request string into an array of coordinates" do
      player_input = "3, 3, 5, 5"
      translated_array = @game.translate_move_request_to_coordinates(player_input)
      translated_array.should == [3, 3, 5, 5]
    end
```

The test passes, but I think the code is pretty ugly. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Steve

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could replace the explicit iteration of `each` by a map operation:

```
move_request.chomp.split(',').map { |x| x.to_i }
```

A more concise way of writing this as proposed by @tokland is :

```
move_request.chomp.split(',').map(&:to_i)
```

It avoids explicitly writing a block and also choosing a variable name like `x` which is not relevant as any name would do.

Please have a look at stackoverflow post [What does to_proc method mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14881476/452614)

Comment: move_request.split(",").map(&:to_i)

Comment: +1: I didn't know it. There an interesting explanation of it in the book "Programming Ruby 1.9" from the [Pragmatic Bookshelf](http://pragprog.com/) in section "The Symbol.to_proc Trick" on page 363 (4th printing, May 2011).