# What does to_proc method mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, syntax, block, symbols, proc

I am learning rails and following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961030). I am stuck with the `to_proc` method. I consider symbols only as alternatives to strings (they are like strings but cheaper in terms of memory). If there is anything else I am missing for symbols, then please tell me. Please explain in a simple way what `to_proc` means and what it is used for.

Comment: The other answers are great for answering how `to_proc` can be used in practice. However I found these simple documentation links a better answer for "what is it", including "what is a `Proc`", which is what `to_proc` returns. https://apidock.com/rails/Symbol/to_proc https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Proc.html

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Some methods take a block, and this pattern frequently appears for a block:

```
{|x| x.foo}
```

and people would like to write that in a more concise way. In order to do that they use a combination of: a symbol, the method `Symbol#to_proc`, implicit class casting, and `&` operator. If you put `&` in front of a `Proc` instance in the argument position, that will be interpreted as a block. If you combine something other than a `Proc` instance with `&`, then implicit class casting will try to convert that to a `Proc` instance using `to_proc` method defined on that object if there is any. In case of a `Symbol` instance, `to_proc` works in this way:

```
:foo.to_proc # => ->x{x.foo}
```

For example, suppose you write:

```
bar(&:foo)
```

The `&` operator is combined with `:foo`, which is not a `Proc` instance, so implicit class cast applies `Symbol#to_proc` to it, which gives `->x{x.foo}`. The `&` now applies to this and is interpreted as a block, which gives:

```
bar{|x| x.foo}
```

Comment: Plus, according to this <http://thenewstack.io/how-to-write-ruby-faster-at-the-source-code-level/>, it's 20 times faster during runtime.

Comment: I understand `&proc` gives a block, `&x` results in x becoming proc then whole thing also gives a block. I also understand that Symbol has to_proc method. However the part i dont understand and i feel this answer lacks, is how symbol and methods are connected. i mean it's not like all methods are also available by the symbol names

Comment: @MuhammadUmer You can call a method on an object like `1.to_s` and `1.send(:to_s)`. So really `(1..10).each(&:to_s)` is equivalent to `(1..10).each { |x| x.send(:to_s) }`. The symbol is passed as an argument to the `send()` method. Look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9932720/4812050).

Comment: @MuhammadUmer In other words, yes, it is indeed like all methods are also available by the symbol names. That's how Ruby stores method names internally.

Answer (score 49):

The easiest way to explain this is with some examples.

```
(1..3).collect(&:to_s)  #=> ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Is the same as:

```
(1..3).collect {|num| num.to_s}  #=> ["1", "2", "3"]
```

and

```
[1,2,3].collect(&:succ)  #=> [2, 3, 4]
```

Is the same as:

```
[1,2,3].collect {|num| num.succ}  #=> [2, 3, 4]
```

to_proc returns a Proc object which responds to the given method by symbol.
So in the third case, the array [1,2,3] calls its collect method and. succ is method defined by class Integer. So this parameter is a short hand way of saying collect each element in the array and return its successor and from that create a new array which results in [2,3,4]. The symbol :succ is being converted to a Proc object so it call the Array's succ method.

Comment: just wondering if there is a typo in your answer here. Did you mean on line 2 to say '... #succ is a method defined by class Integer ...'? (V helpful answer for my proc learning exercise anyway, thank you.)

Answer (score 9):

For me the clearest explanation is seeing a simple implementation of it.  Here's what it might look like if I were reimplementing Symbol#to_proc:

```
class Symbol  # reopen Symbol class to reimplement to_proc method
  def to_proc
    ->(object) { object.send(self) }
  end
end

my_lambda = :to_s.to_proc

puts my_lambda.(1)  # prints '1'; .() does the same thing as .call()
puts my_lambda.(1).class  # prints 'String'

puts [4,5,6].map(&:to_s)  # prints "4\n5\n6\n"
puts [4,5,6].map(&:to_s).first.class  # prints 'String'
```

Comment: This isn't entirely accurate, because it creates a lambda, while the original `Symbol#to_proc` does not.

Comment: @BobRodes Interesting, I did not think to check that. So it should be `Proc.new { |object| object.send(self) }`?

Comment: I had that feeling, too, and tried it. I'd say it's closer, but when I ran it in `irb`, the monkey-patched version of `:foo.to_proc` gave me this: `#<Proc:0x00007f8e132627a0@(irb):19>`, while the original gave me this: `#<Proc:0x00007ffcb31d5fd0(&:foo)>`. I tried running the patch from a file called `test.rb` and got this: `#<Proc:0x00007fc4fa174f00@test.rb:35>`. Apparently, in the patch version, `self` refers to the main environment rather than the symbol, so there must be more to it.

Comment: I just ran a test on it, though, and it seems to work ok. Test is this method (have to make it public specifically for reasons that aren't fully clear to me): `public; def foo; "Hi, I'm foo."; end`, and this call: `p [''].map(&:foo)`. Works with the original and the monkey-patch.

Answer (score 2):

For anybody still a bit stumped, running the following code might make things a little clearer:

```
class Symbol
  def to_proc
    proc do |obj|
      puts "Symbol proc: #{obj}.send(:#{self})"
      obj.send(self)
    end
  end
end

class Array
  def map(&block)
    copy = self.class.new
    self.each do |index|
      puts "Array.map:   copy << block.call(#{index})"
      copy << block.call(index)
    end
    copy
  end
end

remapped_array = [0, 1, 2].map &:to_s
puts "remapped array: #{remapped_array.inspect}"
```

These are not the actual implementations of `Symbol.to_proc` or `Array.map`, they are just simplified versions which I'm using to demonstrate how `map &:to_s` and similar calls work.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted !!! Thanks