# Can any one explain the use of '&' in this piece of ruby code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Can any one explain the use of '&' in this piece  of ruby code?

```
s.feature_addons.select(&:is_active?)
```

Comment: It's just a shortcut for `s.feature_addons.select {|a| a.is_active?}`.  You'll often see it with `map`, `inject`, and other methods, not just with `select`. |

Comment: The question that @not-rightfold linked to has a nicer discussion on that.

Comment: @sawa provided a very good explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14881125/what-does-to-proc-method-mean).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means:

```
s.feature_addons.select { |addon| addon.is_active? }
```

The `&` calls `to_proc` on the object, and passes it as a block to the method.

```
class Symbol
  def to_proc
    Proc.new { |*args| args.shift.__send__(self, *args) }
  end
end
```

U can define `to_proc` method in other classes: [Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5128073/2087368)

Answer (score 3):

That's a shortcut for `to_proc`. For example, the code you provided is the equivalent of:

```
s.feature_addons.select {|addon| addon.is_active?}
```

Some old documentation for it can be found here:

http://apidock.com/rails/Symbol/to_proc (when it was provided by ActiveSupport)

It then became a part of Ruby core in 1.9

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Symbol.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use this syntax as shorthand for methods to apply to an entire collection.

It is functionally the same as:

```
s.feature_addons.select { |a| a.is_active? }
```

You can use it with any collections, such as:

```
User.all.map(&:id)
```

etc