# Enumerating empty/nil, the Ruby way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a Rubier way to do

```
if !arr.blank?
  arr.map{|x| x.do_something}
end
```

for empty arrays in Ruby, and empty relations in Rails

Comment: `arr.blank? || arr.map { ... }` is one terser way I can think of.

Comment: Do we need to check `arr.blank?` condition (given `arr.class == Array`)? Doing map on blank array returns blank array. What are the benefits of checking `arr.blank?`

Comment: There's something funny about this code: #map leaves the original array untouched, returning a new array which would become the result of the if statement, but the result of the if statement is not used.  Did you mean `map!` instead of `map`?

Answer (score 2):

You would use this for arrays that might be empty or even `nil`:

```
Array(arr).map(&:do_something)
```

For relations in Rails it is just the following, because Rails' relations do not return `nil`:

```
relation.map(&:do_something)
```

Comment: No, it does not give an error. If `arr` is `nil` it just does not do anything. Try `Array(nil).map(&:foo)` in your console. No error at all!

Answer (score 2):

You can shorten it to one line using `unless`. Also use [Symbol#to_proc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14881125/what-does-to-proc-method-mean) instead of explicit block:

```
arr.map(&:do_something) unless arr.blank?
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to avoid negative logic for a condition determination if possible. So instead of

```
if !arr.blank?
  arr.map{|x| x.do_something}
end
```

you can write

```
if arr.present?
  arr.map{|x| x.do_something}
end
```

Inclusion is always a faster operation than exclusion.

Answer (score 0):

So if you have an array which may have nil values you can just use `Array#compact` which return array without nil values.

```
2.2.0 :013 > arr = [1, nil, "2"]
2.2.0 :014 > arr.compact
 => [1, "2"]
```

If the array is empty `#map` method won't have any side effects so you are safe and you don't have to check if array is empty.